# Replace git pull with git up

Tags: git, git-pull

I use [`git up`](https://github.com/aanand/git-up) in order to avoid [merge bubbles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26239379/what-is-a-merge-bubble), but sometimes I accidentally issue a `git pull`.

What is the best way to systematically replace a `git pull` with a `git up`?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/a/105389/90644

Comment: Thanks @Anatoly, do you know any git specific way? For example some configuration in the .gitconfig?

Comment: Cant you alias pull to up? `git config --global alias.pull up`?

Comment: @RedX Unfortunately this is not possible as stated [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config): *To avoid confusion and troubles with script usage, aliases that hide existing Git commands are ignored*.

Comment: That is very understandable and at the same time a pitty.

Comment: Instead of avoiding `pull`, why not configure it to work a way more to your liking? You can set up `git pull --rebase` as the default.

Comment: Replacing `git pull` by something that does *a whole lot more* without having the ability to *just do* a git pull seems like a very bad idea. I can understand the reason for git-up, but using it all the time? Not so sure…

Comment: @poke: I do think that your comment is really useful, so in my answer I decided to write a function that asks you to confirm the git pull before executing it, but still leaves you the opportunity to use it if you really want.

Comment: That seems like a good compromise, good job!

Comment: You can set git pull to rebase with `git config --global pull.rebase true`. Doing so would be sufficient to avoid creating merge bubbles via git pull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the [git-config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) documentation, it is not possible to alias an existing git command.

We can use a bash function that asks you to confirm that you want to actually use the `git pull` command, and also offers you the opportunity to use `git up` instead:

```
function git() {
    if [[ $@ == "pull" ]]; then
        read -p "Do you want to [p]ull, [u]p or [a]bort? " yn
        case $yn in
            [Pp]* ) command git pull;;
            [Uu]* ) command git up;;
            * ) echo "bye";;
        esac
    else
        command git "$@"
    fi
}
```

### Example

```
$ git pull
 Do you want to [p]ull, [u]p or [a]bort? u
 Fetching origin
 master up to date
$ git pull
 Do you want to [p]ull, [u]p or [a]bort? p
 Already up-to-date.
$ git pull
 Do you want to [p]ull, [u]p or [a]bort? a
 bye
```

Comment: I think that will fail on `git pull` with additional arguments (which can either precede or follow the `pull` command).

Comment: @KeithThompson If `git pull` is issued with additional arguments it normally means that you *wanted* to do a git pull (the completions could be quite messy otherwise). So this was an intended behaviour when I scripted it.

Comment: And you're using `[[ ... ]]`, not `[ ... ]`, so it won't misbehave in the way I initially thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

As a de-facto mentor of mine used to say

> I don't define aliases, I type the whole commands so that I don't forget them eventually.

In other fords, just do

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master  # fails due to local changes
git stash
git rebase origin master
git stash pop
```

Yes, it's a lot of typing. That is not a bug, it's a feature. If/when a step fail, you have to go examine **why**.

It forces you to *think* about your work. Just the same as `make small commits with long commit messages`.